# Change the position of text in pgf-umlcd aggregation

Tags: positioning, pgf-umlcd

I need to change the position of text written on top of aggregation relation in `pgf-umlcd`. Here is what I've written so far:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[show background grid]
    \begin{class}[text width=10cm]{StateSpace}{7,0}
        \attribute{- stateToActionSet: HashMap<State, HashMap<Action, Double>{}>}
        \operation{+ addState(s: State)}
        \operation{+ size()}
        \operation{+ updateQValueForAction(s: State, a: Action, qValue: Double)}
    \end{class}
    \begin{class}{State}{12,-5}
        \attribute{+ latency: Integer}
        \attribute{+ isLoadIncreasing: Boolean}
    \end{class}
    \begin{interface}{Action}{4,-5}
        \operation[0]{+ toString()}
    \end{interface}
    \begin{class}[text width=3cm]{NoAction}{0,-8}
        \implement{Action}
        \operation{+ toString()}
    \end{class}
    \begin{class}[text width=3cm]{ScaleIn}{4,-8}
        \implement{Action}
        \operation{+ toString()}
    \end{class}
    \begin{class}[text width=3cm]{ScaleOut}{8,-8}
        \implement{Action}
        \operation{+ toString()}
    \end{class}
    
    \aggregation{StateSpace}{states}{1..*}{State}
    \aggregation{StateSpace}{actionSet}{1..*}{Action}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{State Space Class Diagram}
\end{figure}
```

which results in:
[image: Text position]

As you see, the text has been positioned on top of aggregation line. Is there any way to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to argue that the simplest way will be to add these via plain Ti*k*Z methods.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[simplified]{pgf-umlcd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[show background grid]
    \begin{class}[text width=10cm]{StateSpace}{7,0}
        \attribute{- stateToActionSet: HashMap<State, HashMap<Action, Double>{}>}
        \operation{+ addState(s: State)}
        \operation{+ size()}
        \operation{+ updateQValueForAction(s: State, a: Action, qValue: Double)}
    \end{class}
    \begin{class}{State}{12,-5}
        \attribute{+ latency: Integer}
        \attribute{+ isLoadIncreasing: Boolean}
    \end{class}
    \begin{interface}{Action}{4,-5}
        \operation[0]{+ toString()}
    \end{interface}
    \begin{class}[text width=3cm]{NoAction}{0,-8}
        \implement{Action}
        \operation{+ toString()}
    \end{class}
    \begin{class}[text width=3cm]{ScaleIn}{4,-8}
        \implement{Action}
        \operation{+ toString()}
    \end{class}
    \begin{class}[text width=3cm]{ScaleOut}{8,-8}
        \implement{Action}
        \operation{+ toString()}
    \end{class}
    \aggregation{StateSpace}{}{}{State}
    \aggregation{StateSpace}{}{}{Action}

    \path (StateSpace) -- (State) node[midway,sloped,above]{states}
    node[midway,sloped,below] {1..*};
    \path (StateSpace) -- (Action) node[midway,sloped,above]{actionSet}
    node[midway,sloped,below] {1..*};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]